# Batch commit for psycopg2 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am new to python. I have a use case in which I have to parse a CSV file and then have to insert the rows into DB.

Here is my code

```
with open(targetFileName, 'r') as csvfile:
        # creating a csv reader object 
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
        for row in csvreader:
            print(row)
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute("insert into test (first, second) values(%s,%s)",row)
                conn.commit()
```

Here I am executing and committing query row by row. I want to do batch commit rather than committing each row. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it, but can't you put the for loop inside the 2nd with statement, and the commit after the for loop?

```
with open(targetFileName, 'r') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv reader object 
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        for row in csvreader:
            print(row)
            cur.execute("insert into test (first, second) values(%s,%s)",row)
        conn.commit()
```

You could also consider using the execute_batch command in Psycopg2:

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers